# Replace Desktop with WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, integration, desktop

Wondering if it is possible to replace the desktop (ie. icons, wallpaper) with a WPF Window, Frame or something that I can interact with using WPF and C#? I also don't want it to hide when Show Desktop is clicked.

I'm guessing I'll need to use some Win32 APIs or something? Anyone have any examples, or can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How do I Create a Borderless Window in WPF?](http://learnwpf.com/Posts/Post.aspx?postId=e9cb689c-e6af-407a-b28c-d38f2f2f555c)

Check

1. [3D gadgets for your WPF Desktop](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/3d-gadget-WPF.aspx)

Comment: Please read the question again, he asks to replace windows desktop, icons wallpapers

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Baby Smash!](http://www.hanselman.com/babysmash/) it's a WPF application that sounds like it does most of what you'll want. I believe you can get the source too.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a web page with Silverlight (XAML & C#), then set your desktop to the Web page.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code and pass the window handle to the function while form load hope fully this resolves your problem. to prevent minimize your application use the following code

```
public void SetFormOnDesktop(IntPtr hwnd) {
IntPtr hwndf = hwnd;  
IntPtr hwndParent = FindWindow("ProgMan", null);  
SetParent(hwndf, hwndParent);  
}
```